# Reference nested json object property by string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know I'm missing something obvious here but say I have a JSON object that looks like this:

```
testObj = {
            levelOne: {
                       levelTwo: []
            }
}
```

I also have a string value:

```
var prop = 'levelOne.levelTwo';
```

I'm trying to determine if there's any way to basically do something like this:

```
var x = testObj[prop];
```

That doesn't work, but is there any way to do the equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no trivial way (e.g. `testObj[prop]`) of doing this, but the `reduce` function is well suited:

```js
let nestedProp = (obj, path) =>
 path.split('.').reduce((obj, prop) => obj[prop], obj);

let x = nestedProp({levelOne: {levelTwo: [5]}}, 'levelOne.levelTwo');
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks - I knew there had to be a simple way to do this. This gives me exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic keys to access properties in an object but not multiple levels down.

i.e. You can do `const a = testObject["levelOne"]` but not what you tried. ([Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors))

There are however helper libs that have functions to do this. One example is [lodash.get function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get)